# Prevent Leaflet map from showing rectangle around layer on click

Tags: leaflet

I have a Leaflet map that I load GeoJSON data into. I roll over the polygons with the mouse and click on them.

When I roll over with the mouse, the tooltip to the layer appears in Firefox, but nothing happens when clicking. In Chrome, when I click, a rectangle appears around the corresponding layer. See the attached image.
This is probably the marking of a selection. I do not want this. How can I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Q/A on GIS SE site are not intended only to solve problem of particular user, but be helpful resource for anybody with similar questions/problems. That's the reason question has to be complete in itself and include all relevant code as text, since outside links tend to get lost in time and also that there is no need to visit other sites to get complete picture of what the problem is. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fiddling for a minute or two with the developer tools in my web browsers (specifically, [this](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/index.html#page-inspector) and [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/)), I realized that this is the same issue as "[How to disable black outline in Chrome [in MapboxGL-JS]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67071426) ".

Chrome has a built-in CSS rule (AKA a "user agent stylesheet" rule) with the following:

```
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

Which means "apply an [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) of default colour and 5px wide to [whatever element is currently focused](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)". Clicking on a DOM element capable of receiving user events focuses that element (navigating with a keyboard by pressing `tab` repeteadly does as well). For a bit more background, see also [`activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement).

Armed with this knowledge, it's fairly easy to create a CSS rule to take over chrome's default behaviour, e.g.:

```
path.leaflet-interactive:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Be aware that removing focus from the current active element is [considered harmful to accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus#accessibility_concerns).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are applying the styles incorrectly for L.geoJSON.

There is an option to pass the styles in, which will apply to all features. To customize styles for mouseevents, you can set a listener for that layer in `onEachFeature`.

```
var landkreise = L.geoJSON(landkreise, {
  style: {
    fillColor: '#019137',
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    color: '#019137',  //Outline color
    fillOpacity: 0.1
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.GEN, { permanent: false, direction: "center" });
  }
});
```

Reference: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson